# Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, android-studio

Before stating my problem, I saw similar question related to same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142530/android-addviewview-is-not-supported-in-adapterview). But it doesn't seem to help.

I have the SettingsActivity which gets called when Settings is pressed on Menu.

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v("Settings:OnCreate","Going to set View in SettingsActivity");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Log.v("Settings:OnCreate","View is set in SettingsActivity");

      //When I don't add the below part, activity_settings is displayed properly.
      //I am getting the error when this below part is added
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.activity_settings, new MyPreferenceFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }



    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("Fragment:OnCreate","Going to add preferences");
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
        Log.v("Fragment:OnCreate","Added preferences");
    }

    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
            }
        } else {
            // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

Here is the res/layout/activity_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_settings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

</ListView>
```

Here is the ~res/xml/pref_general.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:title= "@string/pref_location_label"
        android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"   />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I am getting the error when I included the MyPreferenceFragment(). I read the documentation on using [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) and I don't think that I made mistakes in it's implementation. Please help me out in solving this issue.

**Edit:** I am adding the crash stack

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.home.sunshine, PID: 19190
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.home.sunshine/com.example.home.sunshine.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:474)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:990)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:800)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
                      at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6619)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2542)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I just added the entire Error stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your layout. Then, replace:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.v("Settings:OnCreate","Going to set View in SettingsActivity");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Log.v("Settings:OnCreate","View is set in SettingsActivity");

  //When I don't add the below part, activity_settings is displayed properly.
  //I am getting the error when this below part is added
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_settings, new MyPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.v("Settings:OnCreate","Going to set View in SettingsActivity");
    Log.v("Settings:OnCreate","View is set in SettingsActivity");

  //When I don't add the below part, activity_settings is displayed properly.
  //I am getting the error when this below part is added
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep your layout and existing Java code, but change the `activity_settings` widget in the layout to be a `FrameLayout` instead of a `ListView`. This runs a bit more slowly and uses a bit more memory, but it will work.

A `PreferenceFragment` provides its own `ListView`. You do not need one.

Comment: What do you mean by android.R.id.content, what does it do?

Comment: @johnsmith: `android.R.id.content` is a `FrameLayout` provided by the framework. For activities that use `setContentView()`, the content `View` goes into that `FrameLayout`. However, you can also use that `FrameLayout` as the target for fragment transactions.

Comment: Both of your methods work and now I have more clearer idea on fragments. Thank you very much @CommonsWare